# How to I disable UITesting when running tests on a iOS8 device?

Tags: ios, testing, xcode7

I have a project that contains both Unit tests and UI tests. 
The project, per requirement, has to support both iOS8 and iOS9, and is setup with a continuous integration bot that runs tests on every commit to our repos.

I would like the bot to run tests on multiple devices with multiple iOS versions, to ensure as a minimum that our unit tests are valid across multiple OS versions.

However, I am unable to find an option to disable running UITests on devices running OS versions prior to iOS9, as UI testing is not supported on iOS8. However I would still like to run my unit tests on iOS8.

If I try and run my tests directly on the project using iPhone Simulator 8.2 I get the following error message: *"UI Testing is not supported on “iPhone 6 (8.2)” because it is running iOS Simulator 8.2 and UI Testing requires iOS Simulator 9.0 or later."*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a second scheme and remove the UI test from the scheme in the test menu. Then add a bot for that scheme.

Answer (score 12):

Untick the UI Test checkbox from edit scheme can switch it off when running test scheme by Command+U.

[image: Untick UITest checkbox]